# ChatSecure Pods.xcodeproj is missing

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods, xmppframework

I have cloned ChatSecure repo following the instructions given in

https://github.com/ChatSecure/ChatSecure-iOS

Now when I run the project from workspace after pod install, Pods.xcodeproj is greyed out. Also it is missing from the Pods folder on disk.

How can I fix it to run and build my project?

[image]

Comment: delete your pod.lock, pod folder & .workspace file.
And install pod again.

Comment: It didn't work.